# Internal server error 500 when doing a POST request in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm new to web api and l'm testing how to use a post request. First, l created my model class called Student with the following properties.

Here is my model class:

```
   namespace SelfApi.Models
   {
     public class Student
      {
        public string studentId { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set;}
     }
    }
```

Then inside the values controller, l have this code to implement a post request. I imported SelfApi.Models so l can have access to the Student Model class and its properties. In the post request l want to be able to post data and map it directly to the Student Model class.

```
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using SelfApi.Models;

    namespace SelfApi.Controllers
     {

       public class ValuesController : ApiController
        {
          static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

       // POST api/values
       public async Task PostAsync([FromBody] Student student)
        {
          client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:4570/");
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/values",student);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

       }

      } 
    }
```

Now in Postman I choose a POST request, chose json(application/json) and included this in the body fields. Note this json data maps directly to what l have in the Student Model class.

```
{
 "studentId" : "23",

 "firstName" : "John",

 "lastName" : "Black",

 "address" : "DC"
}
```

When l fired the request, l got a 500:Internal Server Error. I'm open to suggestions, if l have my code wrong please tell me. I'm eager to have this worked. I have been on this the whole day. Thanks.

Comment: The information you provided is very vague. Please include any stack trace you have available.

Comment: You post to this endpoint, then inside the endpoint your post to it again? Over and over again? At some point it either runs out of stack space or `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` kicks in, because nowhere do you return an `Ok()`

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it entirely wrong, the `httpclient` class if for when you want to call an action from your client but in your server you have to actually process the request, the way you did it causes an infinite loop that request comes to your server and then again it sends to server over and over again, you have to do sth like this in your controller

```
    namespace SelfApi.Controllers
 {

   public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
      private AppDataBaseContext DB = new AppDataBaseContext();

   // POST api/values
   public async Task PostAsync([FromBody] Student student)
    {
      DB.Student.Add(student);
      await DB.SaveChangesAsync();
return Ok();
   }

  } 
}
```

which AppDataBaseContext  is your ef DbContext.